# word-wrap error in firefox, works in safari and chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, word-wrap

Please view the below code as html in both firefox, and other browsers such as chrome or safari.

[ ] ( ) and other \W character seems to cause word-wrap to produce premature wrapping

As specified by firefox, word-wrap is fully implemented.

```
<style>
    div.working {background:blue; height:400px; width:130px;}
    div.notWorking {background:red; height:400px; width:130px;}
    div {oveflow:hidden; word-wrap: break-word; font-family:monospace}
</style>

<div class="working">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>

<div class="notWorking">[X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X]</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: As mentioned above it is working fine in FF 11.0. I do remember having issues with word-wrap not working in older versions of Firefox. But then word-wrap was not implemented properly in those versions.

Comment: I was trying to post some screenshots, but becuase of my n00b status on this site, it won't let me. I guess i didn't really try to explain the effect I am going for. With the string of As, the browser wrap when the As reach the limitation of the div's width. Where as with the [X] the browser wraps after the bracket. I believe this have to do with what the browser considers as a word. this can be easily fixed with pre and <br/> inserted using JS. But a JS free solution would be interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a comprehensive list of special characters/strings to avoid if you intent to not have premature warping.

```
'][',')(','}{','-','><','\/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with the `word-wrap` property; Firefox considers `[X][X]` to be one word, and will wrap appropriately. I don't know what the list of punctuation characters that triggers this special behaviour is though.

Comment: I noticed this also, but i am trying really hard to find a way around these special characters. because it is really easy to hack a div to add <br/> according to your taste of wrapping length. But for a textarea I can't seem to figure any solutions.